# Jsoup: extract everything between 2 random tags

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I got HTML file:

```
<div>test</div>
abc
<content >
<!--alo 123-->
<div>content alo 123  here</div>
</content>
yes
<div>test</div>
```

I am trying to get get everything between to  tags with result like this ( inlude text):

```
    abc
    <content >
    <!--alo 123-->
    <div>content alo 123  here</div>
    </content>
    yes
```

I got this code in java:

```
 previousTag=selectedTag.previousElementSibling();
 nextTag=selectedTag.nextElementSibling();
```

I tried to add after previousTag with:

```
 previousTag.append("<gf>");
   nextTag.before("</gf>");
```

But the beforeTag is automatically add "`</gf>`". And nextTag did not do a thing.

i also tried to get everything after the prevoiusTag with:

```
 int iPrevious=previousTag.elementSiblingIndex();
 Elements selection=previousTag.getElementsByIndexGreaterThan(iPrevious);
```

in attempt to  get everything after the "prevoiusTag"and "nextTag", it did not work in the end.
I looked into another article with same issue but can't apply.
They knew what their tag is.
I am avoiding to use loop for with list_sibling_nodes.
Have anyone know how to extract everything between 2 random tags??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are two options for solving your problem.

#### Option 1: CSS query approach

Jsoup will handle all the dirty job for you. This approach works **only** if you are not interested with sibling `TextNodes`.

```
div:containsOwn(test):first-of-type ~ *:not(div:containsOwn(test), div:containsOwn(test):last-of-type ~ *)
```

Remember : *Since `*` operator matches only elements, text nodes won't be matched.*

[DEMO](http://try.jsoup.org/~3gYrKNqqgvu_t7Q8sJg_3B7Eb-0)

***DESCRIPTION:***

```
div:containsOwn(test)  /* Select a div containing directly the text `test` */
:first-of-type         /* Keep only the first div found (1) */
~ *                    /* Select all siblings of (1) ... */
:not(                  /* ... excluding ... */
    div:containsOwn(test)  /* ... any div containing directly the text `test` */
    ,                      /* OR */
    div:containsOwn(test):last-of-type ~ *) /* any sibling after the second div (second random tag) */
) /* :not operator closing parenthesis */
```

#### Option 2: API approach

The code below inspects each sibling node manually between your two chosen elements (two random tags). It stops when the second random element is found.

```
String firstRandomElementSelector = "div:containsOwn(test):first-of-type";
String secondRandomElementSelector = "div:containsOwn(test):last-of-type";

Document doc = ...;
Element firstRandomElement = select(doc, firstRandomElementSelector);
Element secondRandomElement = select(doc, secondRandomElementSelector);

List<Node> siblingNodes = firstRandomElement.siblingNodes();
List<Node> nodesInBetween = new ArrayList<>();

Node currentNode = firstRandomElement;
do {
   Node nextSibling = currentNode.nextSibling();
   if (nextSibling == null) {
      break;
   }

   if (secondRandomElement.equals(nextSibling)) {
      break;
   }

   nodesInBetween.add(nextSibling);
   currentNode = nextSibling;
} while(true);

for(Node node : nodesInBetween) {
   System.out.println(node.outerHtml() + "---");
}

// Helper method
private static Element select(Document doc, String cssSelector) {
   Element element = doc.select(cssSelector).first();
   if (element == null) {
       throw new RuntimeException("Unable to locate any element matching:" + cssSelector);
   }
}
```